# Can I encrypt whole hard drive when dual boot Ubuntu/Win 7 installed on same drive? If so what program?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, truecrypt

I am seeking a program that can encrypt a whole hard drive when Ubuntu 12.04/ Windows 7 installed on the same drive (different partitions) using a grub loader. I cannot seem to get TrueCrypt to accept this, and I am curious if there is a work around (lol) or another open source encryption program anyone may suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a self-encrypting hard drive (SED). Not perfect, but they do work, and they don't slow down your system, except for bootup (assuming you are putting the decryption key in the pre-OS-boot sequence).  These are becoming more mainstream in business/enterprise and widely available (Dell sells them as part of a system package, now, e.g.). Here's a vendor page with some info : [Western Ditgal/HGST Self-Encrypting Drives](http://www.hgst.com/internal-drives/self-encrypting-drives/).

Answer (score 0):

Truecrypt and grub don't get along.  You can use bitlocker and chainload grub from boot.ini.  Then use luks on the linux side.

Answer (score 0):

There are several commercial solutions from e.g. Symantec, but they are not cheap.
The simplest solution for that is to use Bitlocker.

greetings